# After completing the square.

Tags: quadratics

After completing the square, what are the solutions to the quadratic equation below?
$$x^2 + 2x = 25$$

[image]

Honstely I think it's B. But I'm not sure.

Comment: No, it is not (b), honestly or not.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

$$25=x^2+2x=(x+1)^2-1\implies (x+1)^2=26\implies x+1=\pm\sqrt{26}$$

Comment: Which means it's "C". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

One can got through the process of completing the square (as in "Timbuc"'s posted answer).  But one could also check by substitution.  So suppose it is proposed that $x=-1+\sqrt{26}$ is a solution.  We would then have
\begin{align}
x^2 + 2x & = (-1+\sqrt{26})^2 + 2(-1+\sqrt{26}) \\[10pt]
& = (1-2\sqrt{26}+26) + 2(-1+\sqrt{26}) \\[10pt]
& = (1+26)-2 \\[10pt]
& = 25,
\end{align}
so that is indeed a solution.  And the same thing works with $-1-\sqrt{26}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the quadratic equation $x^2+bx+c=0$, the sum of the roots is $-b$ and the product is $c$.  So for $x^2+2x-25=0$, the $2$ roots sum to $-2$, which eliminates A and B.  The product is $-25$.  The product of the roots for D is clearly $-24$, which eliminates this answer, leaving C.  And it can be quickly verified

$$(-1+\sqrt{26})(-1-\sqrt{26})=(-1)^2-\sqrt{26}^2=-25$$

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your answrt using this.
The solution to general quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is given by the formula $\frac {-b+\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \frac {-b-\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ 
The given equation is $x^2-2x-25=0$
There fore after applying this formula you will get option c as your answer.